# Would I need to undo a "rails generate scaffold" after I undo a "db:migrate"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rake

I'm new to RoR and I'm following Michael Hartl's tutorial (so feel free to correct the terminology I'm using where you see it fit).  In chapter 2, I created a Users table by running these lines:

```
$ rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Then, I ran the code below to try to create a Microposts table (However, I misspelled Micropost without an 'r'!)...

```
$ rails generate scaffold Miropost content:string user_id:integer
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Now I want to delete the Miropost table I created.  After searching in stackoverflow.com, I understand I can undo the database migration (ie., db:migrate) by running `rake db:migrate:reset`.   My question is would I need to undo the "rails generate scaffold" too?  And when do scaffolds cease to exist?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First you would need to rollback the changes from db. 
Assuming that the migration generated for `Miropost` is the latest migration in your `db`.

Just run

```
rake db:rollback ## This will drop the table miroposts
```

After this destroy the existing scaffold by :

```
rails destroy scaffold Miropost content:string user_id:integer
```

Then all you need to do is to recreate the scaffold with correct spelling and run `rake db:migrate`

Comment: Thanks!  That worked like a charm.  Just for the benefit of my schooling, do scaffolds never get deleted until you explicitly destroy them?  And when one does `rake db:migrate`, does it always refer to the most recent scaffold created?

Comment: `scaffold` would only be deleted when you explicitly delete it with `rails destroy scaffold...` command. `rake db:migrate` will migrate all the pending migrations within `db/migrate` folder.